# How to check if image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible somehow to check is image loaded without function .load() or onLoad? Problem is that the webkit-like browsers doesn't work properly with this function.

**UPDATE:**
Problem is in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG - load fires only once otherwise stream is going and loading new images.

Comment: The `.complete` boolean property will tell you if the image is loaded. So `if ( img.complete ) { ... }`. (Note, though, that it probably isn't implemented in IEold.)

Comment: Webkit browsers support the "load" event for images. What do you mean?

Comment: They do not fire the event if the image is coming from cache.

Comment: @SoonDead Yes. Browsers generally behave like that.

Comment: If I remember correctly IE-s don't.

Answer (score 4):

You can check `img.width` : it's 0 if it's not loaded.

But I'm sure you can use `onload` (all low cap) on webkit browsers too :

```
 img.onload=function(){
     console.log('loaded!');
 };
 img.src='something';
```

Beware a frequent error : you have to set the src **after** you set the onload, or the onload callback won't be called if the image is in cache.

Demonstration : [tested on Chrome, which is webkit based](http://jsfiddle.net/ApqC4/)

Comment: You should have said it immediately. Your title was about "image loaded" while "mjpeg" is a video format.

Answer (score 3):

I used this https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded in a project and it worked fine for me